# Flutter - How to scroll to a specific index item of children in sticky header list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a sticky header list where I need to scroll to a specific child item position within the sticky header list. I have tried many solution like assigning a global key to the child and use the animateTo() method (in this case I'm getting a null render box object when list items are not in viewport.)

Comment: Test the [Scrollable.ensureVisible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html)

Comment: I also tried this solution but didn't work for list inside sticky headers.

Comment: Add your code for us to test.